# When live USB loses power, can't temporarily boot again

Tags: live-usb

I've noticed this on Ubuntu 18.04 live USB Ubuntu 20.04 persistent USB.

When I'm in a live USB session, ocassionally something I'm running freezes the system, I have to force-shutdown by holding down the power button.

When I do this and try to reboot into the system, I see the grub boot menu from the disk but grub refuses to boot saying something like "hd0,1 doesn't exist".

If I boot into my linux OS on disk and mount then unmount the live USB, then everything starts working again (I can boot from the USB again).

What's happening?

My best guess is that there is some bit which is left unflipped when the device loses power unexpectedly, and when it's mounted and unmounted then perhaps it's reset after some sort of a check to see if the filesystem is consistent.

Comment: Yes, that is a good guess. Sometimes the file system for persistence will be damaged by the hard shut down, and it might be possible to repair with `sudo e2fsck -f /dev/sdxn`, where x is the drive letter and n is the partition number. But in the case you describe there might have been some more basic error, maybe in the partition table.

Comment: If the downvote reason is shared I can try to improve the question

Comment: Next time, try to poweroff or reboot gracefully according to [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/995286/restart-ubuntu-via-keyboard/997223#997223) before resorting to the power button. (I upvoted, did *not* downvote.)